# Copy nodeset from Keys to Variable

Tags: xslt

I have a key:
`<xsl:key name="colorNumKey" match="color" use="@id"/>`.

And i know there are 5 nodeset selected (5 different `<colour>` elements) in the key. Is it possible if i can copy these 5 nodeset in the variable? So i can use Variable nodeset for processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible. How to do it, it really depends on the context.

Example, in the context of the `color` parent (let say `colors`), you can use:

```
<xsl:template match="colors">
 <xsl:variable name="children" select="key('colorNumKey',*/@id)"/>
 <!-- use $children -->
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks Empo..  it worked.. :-)

Earlier i was trying:
`<xsl:variable name="children">   
  <xsl:value-of select="key('colorNumKey',*/@id)"/>  
</xsl:variable>`

And it was taking only 1st node. Any idea why?

Comment: In that way, you were saving in the variable only text. Read [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#value-of). It was taking only the 1st node...depending on the context.